# Page, Dialog and update panel issue

Tags: asp.net, application-pages, aspx, updatepanel

I have page, where user can choose where he wants to copy library element. Since copying can take longer time, I'd like to give some information that actually something is going on. It is also important that I'm using `dialog.master` for displaying this page in modal dialog.

To show processing message, I created `UpdatePanel` with label:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="Infobox" runat="server">
  <ContentTemplate>
    <div class="ui-state-highlight">
      <asp:Label ID="StatusLabel" runat="server" Text="">
      </asp:Label>
    </div>
  </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I also created `UpdateProgress` to display spinner image and text that something is going on:

```
<asp:UpdateProgress ID="Progress" runat="server"
AssociatedUpdatePanelID="Infobox">
  <ProgressTemplate>
  <img alt="Postep" src="/_layouts/images/ajax-loader.gif" />Trwa
  przenoszenie zasobu...</ProgressTemplate>
</asp:UpdateProgress>
```

I also added handler to OK button click event of dialog.master where I perform actual copying and after it is finished, I set text of `StatusLabel`. But content of `UpdateProgreess` never shows up, only the text of status label after copying is finished. I tried to register `OkButton` as UpdatePanel's trigger, but with no luck. I tried:

```
<Triggers>
  <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="OkButton" /><%--That gives exception that OkButton cant be found within update panel--%>
</Triggers>
```

and

```
<Triggers>
  <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="OkButton"
  EventName="Click" />
</Triggers>
```

I think what I'm looking for is way to make `OkButton` trigger update on `UpdatePanel`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to keep all relevant controls (including buton) inside updatepanel. No need to use trigger here. If you keep button outside, it will be a postback and you will not see updateprogress.

Answer (score 1):

since what you are trying to achieve is to show some kind of loading or processing indicator due to the long running operation. Have you tried SharePoint
[SPLongOperation](http://peterheibrink.wordpress.com/2009/09/07/splongoperation/)

Hope this helps

Comment: shouldn't this be a comment instead of an answer ?